# jQuery map function append the image element as object

Tags: jquery

this is my function :

```
var listImg = params.list.find('img'), naviHtml = '<ul>';

$.map ( listImg, function ( img, i ) {

        naviHtml += '<li>'+ img + '</li>'
        //naviHtml += '<li><img width=150 height=50 src=' + $(img).attr('src') + '></li>'

    })

    naviHtml += '</ul>'

    console.log(naviHtml);
```

when i console or append to body element, it giving the result as like this:

```
<ul><li>[object HTMLImageElement]</li><li>[object HTMLImageElement]</li><li>[object HTMLImageElement]</li><li>[object HTMLImageElement]</li><li>[object HTMLImageElement]</li><li>[object HTMLImageElement]</li><li>[object HTMLImageElement]</li><li>[object HTMLImageElement]</li></ul>
```

since i am not getting the images, how can i make the htmlimageElement object  to html regular element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var listImg = params.list.find('img'), 
    $navi = $('<ul>');

$.each( listImg, function (img, i) {
  $('<li>').append(img).appendTo($navi);
});

console.log( $navi.html() );
```

Comment: I would use `$(img).clone()` instead of just `img`.Otherwise you will move fetched `img`s to `<ul>`.

Comment: @Engineer Depends on the intended use. Not necessary if the `<img>` is freshly constructed.

Answer (score 0):

By creating a tag and setting the attributes:

```
naviHtml += '<li><img width="'+img.width+'" height="'+img.height+'" src="'+img.src+'" /></li>';
```

Comment: i my commented line itself work fine.  but we can't append the source directly?

Comment: I forgot you can pass an object directly to jquery. See Tomalak's answer

Comment: nope, your suggession is good for my case. i need to change the width and height. thanks